# GsonFactory error in google analytics v3 on android

Tags: android

```
public static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY=GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
```

this code is not showing any error, but when compiling with Gradle, it is giving errors:

```
Error:(49, 65) error: cannot find symbol method getDefaultInstance().
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is the type mismatch.

Here is the type you want :

```
public static final JsonFactory
```

Here is the type you create :

```
GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
```

JsonFactory != GsonFactory, right ?

Comment: The code was correct, GsonFactory use to be the way to create a new JsonFactory but the newer versions of the Google Analytics has changes and GsonFactory is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need.

```
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;

private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
```

The HelloAnalytics example is out of date but the samples in Github are updated more often. https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code if you are trying to access Google's services. All you gotta do is make sure you are importing right package/class/library.

I think you are importing this:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
```

You need to import this:

```
com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory
```

It's just a minor mistake. Just read before you press the tab button.